# Mysql join with 5 table or stored procedure/function

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to join 4 tables : Location, Animal, Person, Organization and Address.

Input will be group id ie  70

Requirement :

- Get the latest location of the animal , based on received date.
- Get the animal name from animal table.
- if there is a person_id for that animal ,in the location table, get the person first name and last name from Person table and address information.
- If organization id is there in location , get the organization name and address
  from Organization table and address table.

How can I join these 5 tables in one query for a given organization id of 70:

Sample Table structure with Data :

Table location

```
 id | group_id | person_id | organization_id | fees1 |fees2 |fees3| received_date |animal_id |
  23| 70       | 12        | 0               | 10    |10    |0    |  2017-11-11   | 1        |
  24| 70       | 1         | 0               | 10    |10    |0    |  2017-10-11   | 1        |
```

Table Animal

```
  id| animal_name |group_id|
  1 | demo | 22   | 70
```

Table Person

```
 id | first_name | last_name |
 1 | Sam        | Dam       |
```

Table Organization

```
 id | org_name |
 77 | test_org |
```

Table Address

```
 id | organization_id | person_id | address1    | country|
 45 |  0              | 1         | test address| USA    |
```

Expected output for group_id 70

Output :

```
 location.id  | location.group_id | location.person_id | location.organization_id | fees1 |fees2 |fees3| received_date | animal_id | animal_name | first_name |address1       |
 23           | 70                |  1                 | 70                       | 20    |20    |20    | 2017-11-11   |   1       |  demo        |  Sam       | test address |
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Where did you run into difficulty?

Comment: For some hints, you'll want to look at `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` and `MAX`.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. Take a look at the joining documentation on the MySQL developers site.

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns, alarm bells should start ringing

Comment: select  a.id, a.name, a.species, a.group_animal_id, 
      l.date_in,l.comments,l.action_min,l.adoption_fee,l.supplies,l.boarding,l.training,l.person_id , 
      p.first_name, p.last_name,    l.organization_id , org.org_name
      from location l    
      left join animal a on  l.animal_id=a.id   
      left join organization org on l.organization_id = org.id  
      left join person p on l.person_id = p.id    
      where l.group_id = 70 order by l.date_in
I tried the above one, but it has duplicate from location table as an animal can have multiple entries in location

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below queries

```
select  l.id,l.group_id,l.person_id,l.organization_id,l.fees1,l.fees2,l.fees3,max(l.received_date) as received_date,l.animal_id,p.first_name,aa.address1 from  Organization as o inner join location as l on o.id=l.organization_id left join Person as p on l.person_id=p.id inner join Animal as a on l.animal_id=a.id  inner join Address as aa on o.id=aa.organization_id where o.id=70 limit 1
```

or

```
select  l.id,l.group_id,l.person_id,l.organization_id,l.fees1,l.fees2,l.fees3,l.received_date,l.animal_id,p.first_name,aa.address1 from  Organization as o inner join location as l on o.id=l.organization_id left join Person as p on l.person_id=p.id inner join Animal as a on l.animal_id=a.id  inner join Address as aa on o.id=aa.organization_id where o.id=70  order by l.received_date desc limit 1
```